# Nginx how to map multiple location in regex to a single directory

Tags: nginx

My application uses a single web app (in HTML and Javascript) to serve multiple (dynamic amount) system.

Systems are distinguished by URL like `http://localhost/sites/<system-id>`, where `system-id` allows only lowercase letter.

Suppose that the web app is located in `/opt/myapp`. How to config that in nginx?

I tried following methods but none works.

```
location ~ /sites/[a-z]+ {
   alias /opt/myapp;
   index index.html index.htm; 
}
```

Enter `http://localhost/sites/abc/`, got `403 forbidden`.

Enter `http://localhost/sites/abc/index.html`, still `403 forbidden` and URL auto changed to `http://localhost/sites/abc/index.html/`

Same result for `location ~ /sites/[a-z]+/ {}`

I tried

```
location ~ /sites/[a-z]+ {
   alias /opt/myapp/;
   index index.html index.htm; 
}
```

Enter `http://localhost/sites/abc`, URL redirected to `http://localhost/sites/abc/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `alias` directive within a *regular expression* `location` must form the complete path to the file.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/sites/[a-z]+(/.*)?$ {
    alias /opt/myapp$1;
    index index.html index.htm; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.